# How Bluetooth Passkey protects agains MITM attack

Tags: security, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am reading Bluetooth Low Energy: The developer handbook and confused about the protection against MITM.

The book says after exchange pairing informations, a random number is generated on both side. Along with that random number, a confirmation value is calculated. The confirmation value is then exchanged between both parties, followed by a reveal of random number.

The exchanged messages are like this in pairing.

```
[Apr 25 18:04:43.919]  [SMP Send]  LE SMP Pairing Request Command
[Apr 25 16:53:09.005]  [SMP Receive]  LE SMP Pairing Response Command 
[Apr 25 16:53:09.019]  [SMP Send]  LE SMP Pairing Confirm Command 
[Apr 25 16:53:14.016]  [SMP Receive]  LE SMP Pairing Confirm Command 
[Apr 25 16:53:14.017]  [SMP Send]  LE SMP Pairing Random Command 
[Apr 25 16:53:14.076]  [SMP Receive]  LE SMP Pairing Random Command
```

The book claims that this prevents MITM from attacking because MITM would have to guess 2^128 possible random numbers to calculate the confirm value.

My question is that how does that help prevent MITM attack. I mean if I am the MITM, I would just pass confirmation number from one end to the other without even need the calculation.

I am sure that I must have missed something.

Comment: I apologize for the link-only answer, but its hard to summarize a video well:  http://www.wimp.com/howencryption/

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher: From the description of the procedure (the random number is revealed in the end) it does not sound like a Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18087908/371137

Comment: those timestamps aren't in order.

Comment: the timestamp is probably a bug in the logging tools. The logs are directly copied from the logging tool. And I think it's the designed sequence from the specification too.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the point of what MITM attacks mean.

By simply passing data received from one device to the other doesn't make you a MITM attacker. Just a MITM.

To "attack" you would have to actually **modify** the data before passing it on without the receiving end noticing it. Ideally you would not just screw up communication, but you would also make meaningful changes (e.g. replace the destination bank account number with yours while keeping the sender's signature, so you get the money instead of the original sender).

By making no modification whatsoever on data that you intercept (before sending), you merely act as a **repeater**.

Answer (score 1):

Attack may not be the intent all the time; MITM may be just interested in tapping the data; The data may be so vital that there is no need to attack/modify, so it depends; just revealing the data itself is damaging enough !!