# Android BluetoothDevice -> connectGatt() Security

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is there any inbuilt security while exchanging data after connecting to a Bluetooth LE device using [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#connectGatt(android.content.Context,%20boolean,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback)) method? Here I wanted to be clarified about the following -

**1. Is the communication channel is secured after device gets connected (but not pared/bonded yet)?**

Or

**2. Is it mandatory to bond/pair the BLE device (using createBond()) to make the communication secured?**

I had a look into the following thread, and the question 4 seems similar to my question.

[Bluetooth Low Energy encryption and data safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963954/bluetooth-low-energy-encryption-and-data-safety?rq=1)

But the answer differs in different response. Please respond if anyone has clarity on this.

Regards,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

1. No, the pairing process is seperate from the connection procedure in LE. You could be connected and exchange data without pairing.
2. When you say secured, do you mean encrypted? There are different features in LE security. You could sign and add integrity without pairing.

Data enncryption requires pairing, regardless of using Secure Simple Pairing or LE Secure Connections.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
With "secured" I mean encrypted, or some other mechanism which prevents MITM to track the data being exchanged.
Also when you are saying signing the data (point 2 in your response), does it means implement my own encryption logic? Can you give some more light on it?

Comment: First of all, encryption does not necessarily protect you from MITM attack. Association model does. Signing in LE does not use OOB, it uses CSRK to sign you data PDU.