# TLS encryption over BLE in Android

Tags: android, ssl, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an android application which pairs to a BLE device and read/write data. Now, my client needs to make this more secure through TLS encryption. I am trying to figure out an efficient way to transfer data via Bluetooth Low Energy between Mobile App & BLE device using TLS/SSL. Could someone please guide me on this?

Comment: See: [Bluetooth Low Energy encryption and data safety](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17963954/295004) I would check if the BLE device is capable of handling the encryption overhead as BLE is for lower power devices.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion TLS has very much overhead and is not really made for the situation with BLE where every saved byte counts. So using TLS over BLE is per definition not efficient. If you still want to do this, you could for example use SSLEngine in Java which is a transport-independent TLS solution. Use L2CAP CoC sockets over BLE instead of GATT to make the I/O simple.